# 'www' domain not working with GitLab pages

Tags: web-hosting, dns, namecheap, jekyll

I have added my domain to the GitLab pages settings and verified it.
The page works fine when accessing it via `example.com`, however `www.example.com` returns a 401 error from GitLab (`You don't have permission to access the resource.`).

My DNS entries:

- `A record @ 35.185.44.232` (The GitLab Server)
- `CNAME record www username.gitlab.io.`
- `TXT record _gitlab-pages-verification-code [verification code]` to verify domain to GitLab
- `URL Redirect Record www https://example.com Unmasked` (This entry does not seem to be working, even after waiting multiple days.)

I'm using Namecheap as domain name provider.
The hosted web page is a Flutter web app in one case, and a static website created with Jekyll in the other.

I have tried re-adding the domain to GitLab pages, but to no avail. The repository is set to public.

Comment: You should redirect www.example.com to example.com, or vice versa

Comment: That's what I tried to do with the last URL Redirect Record. To redirect www to the normal domain. But it's not working.

Comment: DNS doesn't have redirect record, maybe your namecheap DNS has custom rule. Maybe remove your cname record will working

Comment: Did you [verify your domain with GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/custom_domains_ssl_tls_certification/#4-verify-the-domains-ownership)? Also, your `CNAME` record and your "Redirect" (pseudo-)record conflict, you'll want to remove one of them. Remove the `CNAME` if you want your registrar's server to handle the redirect, remove the "Redirect" record if you want GitLab Pages to handle the redirect.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Yes, the domain is verified. 
I removed the CNAME record, leaving only the Namcheap URL redirect, and it seems to work now (even though I think I have browser caching issues, but it works on new browsers and incognito mode). If you write an answer, I'm willing to accept. Thank you!

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur Yes, removing the CNAME record worked. If you write an answer I'm happy to accept it.